# Prefetching initial data and refetch if filter is edited using react-query and next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-query

I am trying to prefetch a data using `react-query` in a NextJs project. This initial data should be changed only if the filter is edited. BTW, there are some State Hooks to control those filters states.

```
function JobSearch(props) {
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
  const [company, setCompany] = useState("");
  const [remote, setRemote] = useState("");
  const [orderBy, setOrder] = useState("date");
  const [location, setLocation] = useState("");

  const { data: jobData, isLoading } = useQuery(
    ["jobs", pageNumber, company, remote, orderBy, location],
    () => fetchJobs(pageNumber, company, remote, orderBy, location),
    { initialData: props.jobs }
  );
  console.log(isLoading);
```

I am logging the loading state(`isLoading`) to see if the prefetching is actually working. Unfortunately it is firstly showing `true` when I load the page.

`<Select>` filter example at my code:

```
<Select
  style={{ width: 200 }}
  onChange={(value) => {
    setRemote(value);
    setPageNumber(1);
  }}
  defaultValue="">
  <option value="">Qualquer</option>
  <option value="true">Remoto</option>
  <option value="false">Presencial</option>
</Select>
```

I am fetching those data using `getStaticProps()`, as below:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const pageNumber = 1;
  const orderBy = "date";

  jobs = await fetchJobs(pageNumber, orderBy);
  return {
    props: {
      jobs,
    },
  };
}
```

What am I missing here to prefetch once and only *re*fetch the data when the filters are edited?

Comment: I'd recommend a read through the official docs: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/ssr#using-nextjs.

Comment: @juliomalves I already did. I even tried to use Hydration instead. But, no success. I think that I am missing something, but I don't know what.

Comment: Actually I think those states are triggering the `useQuery()`. However, the first `isLoading()` log should show `False`.

Comment: you are right, with initialData, you'll never be in `isLoading` state. So my guess is that whatever you pass to initialData is just undefined for whatever reason. Have you logged that?

Comment: Hey guys, I did exactly what @TkDodo suggested and I found out that I was writing the `getStaticProps` in a component located outside `pages/`. So next would never recognize this method and it was getting props as `undefined`.

Comment: I just fixed that, and I am getting another problem now. At this point my page is now running static. But now I need to refetch the information when I change those `Select` filters.

Comment: Just fixed my fetch method inside `getStaticProps`and now it is working! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a whole day debugging it and reading docs. I just found out that I was trying to manipulate a component outside the `pages/` directory. So, as @TkDodo said, probably the props were getting undefined, and it was. After that, I was wrongly passing the params to my axios request method, then, prefetch was failing.

I made the fixes described above and now it is working! Thanks folks!